# Testing Object inside and object

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm writing an image processing application which recognizes objects based on their shapes. The issue that I'm facing is that since one object can be composed of one or more subobjects eg. human face is an object which is composed of eyes, nose and mouth.

Applying image segmentation creates separate objects but does not tells whether one object is inside another object.

How can I check whether an object is contained inside another object effeciently.

For now my algoirthm is wat I would call 8 point test in which u chose 8 points at 8 corners and check whther all of them are inside the object.If they are in then u can more quite certain that entire object is inside another object... But it has got certain limitation or certain areas of failure...

Also just because inner object is inside another object means I should treat them to part of outer object????

Comment: "I'm writing an image processing application" - that probably makes you an expert compared to the majority of people here, given the complexity and specific area....

Comment: @Mitch I disagre... there are quite some very smart users here with a very strong experience in very specific fields... I've seen a few.

Comment: @Camilo Martin: I did not say there wern't smart people here. The point is if you are the person writing an image processing application it kinda implies some expertise in that area, otherwise it's just monkeys and typewriters...

Comment: @Mitch I don't know what you mean by "image processing application". I've wrote several image (video) restoration algorithms and I have the expertise of a monkey. I'm sure there are at least a few of the several thousand (half a million I think) users here at SO that have **some** useful expertise with image processing that could help here.

Comment: @Camilo Martin: "I don't know what you mean by "image processing application"." - that you need to ask the poster...

Comment: @Mitch: when I said I'm writing an "image processing application", I was talking about my BE project which is a content based image search engine. and I'm just a student. I'm doing this project to get more knowledge and practical experience of Image processing apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to test whether one object is fully inside another is to convert both into binary masks using [poly2mask](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/poly2mask.html) (in case they aren't binary masks already), and to test that all pixels of one object are part of the other object.

```
%# convert object 1 defined by points [x1,y1] into mask
msk1 = poly2mask(x1,y1,imageSizeX,imageSizeY);
%# do the same for object 2
msk2 = poly2mask(x2,y2,imageSizeX,imageSizeY);

%# check whether object 1 is fully inside object 2
oneInsideTwo = all(msk2(msk1));
```

However, is this really necessary? The eyes should always be close to the center of the face, and thus, the 8-point-method should be fairly robust at identifying whether you found an eye that is part of the face or whether it is a segmentation artifact.

Also, if an eye is on a face, then yes, you would consider it as part of that face - unless you're analyzing pictures of people that are eating eyes, in which case you'd have to test whether the eye is in roughly the right position on the face.

In sum, the answer to your questions is a big "depends on the details of your application".

Comment: thanx..
but when I gave example of eyes, I was not only referring to human face. I was talking about general objects. Also for large size objects this test would be quite expensive ..

Comment: @Mew 3.2: Object size doesn't matter, since the mask is always the size of the image. Anyway, what I said about eyes applies to any other object, and for more detailed suggestions I need to know more detail about your application.

Comment: my project is regarding content based Image searching. In this project I'm identifying different objects present in an image and listing each object by features in database. Later object based retrieval becomes easy. and My issue was regarding finding out the exact and less time consuming algorithm to find whether an object is inside another Object. This was necessary to find the object composition relation....